# how to reuse results of the request (tSQL)

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to write a stored procedure like the one below

```
allInterestingKeys = SELECT MyKey FROM MyTable WHERE CreatedDate < CAST('2013-01-01' AS date)
DELETE MyTable01 WHERE MyKey IN allInterestingKeys
DELETE MyTable02 WHERE MyKey IN allInterestingKeys 
...
DELETE MyTable10 WHERE MyKey IN allInterestingKeys
```

Ideally I want to run `SELECT MyKey FROM MyTable WHERE ...` only once to make the procedure more efficient and readable than

```
DELETE MyTable01 WHERE MyKey IN (SELECT MyKey FROM MyTable WHERE CreatedDate < CAST('2013-01-01' AS date))
DELETE MyTable02 WHERE MyKey IN (SELECT MyKey FROM MyTable WHERE CreatedDate < CAST('2013-01-01' AS date))
...
DELETE MyTable10 WHERE MyKey IN (SELECT MyKey FROM MyTable WHERE CreatedDate < CAST('2013-01-01' AS date))
```

What is the best way to code it? Thanks.

Comment: What are `MyTableXX`?  Do they have FK references to `MyTable`, and are you planning to delete out of `MyTable` as well; could you use `CASCADE DELETE` on the FK constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a temp table! `SELECT INTO` is the easiest, but you could also design the table ahead of time and `INSERT INTO` the temp table

```
SELECT MyKey 
INTO #allInterestingKeys
FROM MyTable 
WHERE CreatedDate < CAST('2013-01-01' AS date)
```

Then select the list from your temp table

```
DELETE MyTable01 WHERE MyKey IN (SELECT MyKey FROM #allInterestingKeys)
```

Or `INNER JOIN` to the temp table to delete

```
DELETE t
FROM MyTable01 t
INNER JOIN #allInterestingKeys k
  ON t.MyKey = k.MyKey
```